# pandas; make new columns by dividing the last columns of a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe, consisting of 400 columns and >1000 rows. The columns of the dataframe are fixed and will not change. What I want is to do something with the last 120 columns; divide the values in those columns with the value of one other column in the dataframe

My dataframe is like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 .... Column280...Column400
A       2       6            20          40   
B       4       3            20          20
C       3       3            30          9
```

I want to divide Column280 till Column400 with Column2 and add the result of each division to a new column, like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 .... Column280...Column400 .. Column401....Column520
A       2       6            20          40           10           20
B       4       3            20          20           5            5
C       3       3            30          9            10           3


Column401 = Column280/Column2 

Column402 = Column281/Column2 

Column403 = Column282/Column2
```

etc.

I have a list with the columnnames of the last 120 columns, but I have really no idea how to tell pandas to divide those columns and add the result to new columns. Hope that someone can help me here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,(5,400)), columns=range(1, 401)) \
       .add_prefix('Column')
```

**Solution:**

```
df[['Column{}'.format(i) for i in range(401, 401+(400-280)+1)]] = \
    df.loc[:, 'Column280':'Column400'].div(df['Column2'], axis=0)
```

**Result:**

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8  Column9  Column10    ...      Column512  \
0        8        7        3        9       11       14       12       18        6         5    ...       2.714286
1        9       12        4        8        8        2       14       16        9        12    ...       0.166667
2       15        8       11        9       15        0        9       15       16         2    ...       0.000000
3       16       17       12       10        0       15       18        9        9        19    ...       1.117647
4        0       16       17        6        8       17        3        4       17         0    ...       0.812500

   Column513  Column514  Column515  Column516  Column517  Column518  Column519  Column520  Column521
0   0.428571   1.857143   1.714286   0.000000   2.142857   2.428571   1.000000   2.285714   0.571429
1   1.416667   0.750000   0.083333   0.916667   0.166667   1.250000   1.083333   0.500000   1.166667
2   2.000000   0.500000   0.125000   1.875000   1.500000   2.000000   1.000000   1.875000   1.875000
3   0.352941   0.882353   0.470588   0.882353   0.176471   1.000000   0.058824   0.588235   0.941176
4   0.562500   0.687500   0.750000   1.000000   0.750000   0.875000   0.687500   1.000000   1.000000

[5 rows x 521 columns]
```

**Explanation:**

if we want to add a few columns to the DataFrame in one step we can do it this way:

```
df[['new1','new2','new3']] = array
```

where `array` must be of the `(len(df) x 3)` shape or three series with the same as DF length

`df.loc[:, 'Column280':'Column400']` selects all rows and columns starting from `'Column280'` up to `'Column400'` (NOTE: the columns must be lexicographically sorted)

PS [here is a very well documented **Pandas boolean indexing**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

`.div(df['Column2'], axis=0)` divides the DataFrame on the left side to the `df['Column2']` along the `index` axis

Comment: Nice solution ;)

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit for me how this command works? Thanks!

Comment: @Gravel, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

it's the way you think it,

```
df[Column401] = df[Column280]/df[Column2]

df[Column402] = df[Column281]/df[Column2]

df[Column403] = df[Column282]/df[Column2]
```

you can loop through the columns to do the same for all the columns